# about compact metric space and open set.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

let $X$ be a compact metric space and $\{x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_n\}\subset X$. Now let

$$
A=\left\{a>0\,:\, \bigcup_{i=1}^{n} B_{a}\left(x_{i}\right)=X\right\}.
$$

> Prove or disprove : $A$ is open set in $\mathbb{R}$ with euclidean metric.

(note that $B_{a}\left(x_{i}\right)=\{y\in X:d(x_{i},y)>a\}$ )

I think this is true because if $t \in A$ then for every  $t \le t^\prime$ we have  $t^\prime \in A$ so $A=(a,\infty)$ or $A=[a,\infty)$ .

Comment: Note that your solution doesn't quite work, since $[a,\infty)$ is not an open set in $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose $a \in A$, so that $\bigcup_{i=1}^n B_a(x_i) = X$. We will show that there exists $\varepsilon$ such that $(a-\varepsilon, a+\varepsilon)\subset A$, which implies that $A$ is an open set.

For each $y \in X$, there exists $i$ such that $y \in B_a(x_i)$. Since this ball is open, we may define $a_y \in \mathbb{R}^+$ such that $B_{a_y}(y) \subset B_a(x_i)$. Now $\{ B_{\frac{1}{2} a_y}(y) \,:\, y \in X\}$ is an open cover, so by compactness of $X$ we may take a finite subcover:
$$\mathcal{C} = \{ B_{\frac{1}{2}a_{y_1}}(y_1), \ldots, B_{\frac{1}{2}a_{y_m}}(y_m)\}.$$

Choosing $\varepsilon = \min_{1\leq j\leq m}\left( \frac{1}{2}a_{y_j}\right)$, it follows from the definition of $a_y$ that $$\forall 1\leq j\leq m, \,\, B_{\frac{1}{2}a_{y_j}}(y_j) \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^n B_{a-\varepsilon}(x_i) \implies \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}B_{a-\varepsilon}(x_i) = X.$$

Therefore, $a-\varepsilon \in A$, and so $(a-\varepsilon, a+\varepsilon)\subset A$ as required.